# An isomorphism between homology and cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

In the proof of a theorem we did in a class (namely: if $M$ is an odd-dimensional, closed manifold, then $\chi(M)=0$), there's the following step:

> $$H_k(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong H^k(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$$

and then we proceed using Poincaré duality and all the usual homological algebra machinery. It might be something stupid that I'm missing, but I really can't see why the isomorphism above should hold true. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the universal coefficient theorem ($\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a PID):

$$0 \to \operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(H_{i-1}(M; \mathbb{Z}_2), \mathbb{Z}_2) \to H^i(M; \mathbb{Z}_2) \to \hom_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(H_i(M; \mathbb{Z}_2), \mathbb{Z}_2) \to 0$$

Since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field, the $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ term is zero, and since $M$ is a *closed* (thanks Jack Lee) finite dimensional manifold, the homology groups are finitely generated and so are isomorphic to their ($\mathbb{Z}_2$-)dual.

Comment: Of course, this generalizes to any field (and it's also probably possible to do something with the universal coefficient spectral sequence for more general rings, but I can't find a simple condition for PIDs: a self-injective PID is a field, and a ring over which all module are projective is a product of fields).

Comment: Your assertion that "since $M$ is a finite dimensional manifold, the homology groups are finitely generated" is not true. But the OP specified that $M$ is closed, meaning compact with empty boundary, which does imply finitely generated homology.

Comment: @JackLee: Yes, you're of course right, sorry. I forgot the word "closed".